# APIOpenAISwift packages not getting any responses

Tags: ios, swift, openai-api

I am using using [OpenAISwift](https://github.com/adamrushy/OpenAISwift) to work with chatGTP API, I am having an issue with the API that suddenly stopped working. Despite having a valid token and enough credit for API usage, I am not receiving any response from the API. I was previously using the default repo model, but it seems that many models have been shut down by OpenAI. I changed it to `.chat (.chatgpt)` to use GPT-3 and also tested with the GPT-3 turbo model, but I still am not getting any data. This is a crucial issue for my AI-based app, and I would be grateful for any workaround. If it helps, here is my code.

```
@MainActor
class AIViewModel: ObservableObject {

    private var client: OpenAISwift?
    @Published var respnse = ""
    @Published var isLoading = false
    @Published var recievedError = false
    init() { client = OpenAISwift(config: .makeDefaultOpenAI(apiKey: "sk-*******")) }

    func ask(text: String) async {
        isLoading = true
        do {
            let result = try await client?.sendCompletion(
                with: text,
                model: .chat(.chatgpt),
                maxTokens: 200
            )
            let output = result?.choices?.first?.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines) ?? "no answer"
            //print(output)
            self.respnse = output
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            recievedError = true
        }
        isLoading = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `print(error.localizedDescription)` called? Is `client` not nil?

Comment: Unrelated but change the declaration of client to `private let client: OpenAISwift`

Comment: Don’t use OpenAISwift it is known for its terrible error handling and compromising your API key. You can achieve much better error handling with your own URLSession based calls. But you should be making calls via a backend.

Comment: @Larme No! it just doesn't get you any response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably due to using the `OpenAI` [legacy](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/completions-api) endpoint with completion (as mentioned already by Rok Benko)

Try this approach using the more up-to-date `OpenAISwift` code from
[Swift-Almanac OpenAISwift](https://github.com/Swift-Almanac/OpenAISwift) and with `sendChat(...)` instead.

Working example code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import OpenAISwift


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = AIViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(model.respnse)
            .task {
                await model.ask(text: "say hello")
            }
    }
}

@MainActor
class AIViewModel: ObservableObject {

    private let client: OpenAISwift
    
    @Published var respnse = ""
    @Published var isLoading = false
    @Published var recievedError = false
    
    init() {
        self.client = OpenAISwift(config: .makeDefaultOpenAI(apiKey: "sk-xxxxx"))
    }
    
    func ask(text: String) async {
        let chatArr = [ChatMessage(role: .user, content: text)]
        do {
            let results = try await client.sendChat(
                with: chatArr,
                model: .gpt4,
                maxTokens: 200
            )
            print("-----> results: \(results)")
            if let output = results.choices?.first,
               let txt = output.message.content {
                self.respnse = txt
                print("\n-----> respnse: \(respnse)")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I am getting this error:
`error: OpenAISwift.ChatError.Payload(message: "Additional properties are not allowed (\'id\' was unexpected) - \'messages.0\'", type: "invalid_request_error", param: nil, code: nil)`
any idea why?

Comment: Have you removed the https://github.com/adamrushy/OpenAISwift dependency, and
instead, added the https://github.com/Swift-Almanac/OpenAISwift in the `Package Dependencies`
of your project? The code example works well for me, given a valid apikey.
 I get `Hello! How can I assist you today?` On which line of my code do you get the error?

Comment: I am still getting all nils in the response. Anyone else figure this out?

I can share an image if needed.

I am getting error: Additional properties are not allowed (\'id\' was unexpected)

here is some code: 
```
 let client = OpenAISwift(config: .makeDefaultOpenAI(apiKey: apiKey))
        let chatArr = [ChatMessage(role: .user, content: input)]
        return Future<String, Error> { promise in
            client.sendChat(with: chatArr, maxTokens: 1000, completionHandler: { result in
```

Comment: @KinneyKare, it is best to ask your own question with the `specific code you are using`, ie a minimal representative code we can compile and run. It seems you are using some sort of Combine Future code from the Dark Ages. Just use my code that works, you are much better off. **Note** that if you are using a "free" account, and it has runout or reached its time limit, you will not get any response. I recommend you try using the Swift async/await syntax.